# How can I see a log of system changes that have been made to my phone?

Tags: rooting, system, logging, operating-system

Recently my phone suddenly exhibited weird behavior which I remedied by running `com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity`. You can see the exact problem and solution [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245648/275648).

Everything returned to normal and just the way it was before the problem started *except* for a few things that went back to default settings (e.g. I had to reenter wifi passwords).

But now I'm noticing something weird...

A couple of apps/services that I use have suspended and restricted my account. Reaching out to their customer service, one of them is saying it's due to using third party apps/tools, of which I haven't. Something triggered a security violation to warrant a suspension of my accounts. They are not saying what exactly. But putting two and two together, this is right after the problem with my phone.

Another weird thing that happened which is causing me to think that this is the reason I've been suspended is when I opened Titanium backup, there was a pop up message that said that my Android ID has been changed and if I'd like to return it to the previous ID.

Now I want to know what other changes have happened since running `com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity` or since the problem started. How can I find out?

Android 7

Comment: The link in your question does not work. Android does not have a persistent log. That you will run into such problems was very likely after your last question. Therefore I suggested a factory reset.

Comment: restore previous Android ID

Comment: @alecxs Can you suggest a good, free, app that could that? Or a way to do it?

Comment: you mentioned Titanium Backup

Comment: @alecxs Titanium Backup wants me to buy the pro version  to restore it.